# What is the interpretation of the variable description in the variables panel in the IntelliJ IDEA debugger?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a Java application which I am debugging in IntelliJ IDEA. When doing so I see a "Variables" pane like this:

To pick an example, One line says:

```
req = {org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper@22908}"SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade@422b8dc8]]"
```

I know that `req` is a variable in scope at this point in execution, but I don't know how to interpret the rest of this line. How do I read this? What syntax is this? What is the implied relationship between `req` and `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper`? What is the implied relationship between `req` and `FirewalledRequest`? What is the implied relationship between `req` and `RequestFacade`? What do the square brackets mean? What do the `@` symbols mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The representation of objects in the debugger is determined by their full class name, a hex value preceded by `@` and their `toString()` method.

For example, if you look at [SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/servletapi/SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper.java), you can see the following:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ " + getRequest() + "]";
}
```

In turn, the `toString()` method of the `request` is invoked via String concenation, and this gives you the format as you see it.

The square bracket format is somewhat arbitrary, but it generally means that the object within the square brackets is contained by (referred to by, via composition) the outer object.

So in this example, you can see you have a `SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper` which *has-a* `FirewalledRequest` which in turn *has-a* `RequestFacade`.

Objects of classes without an overridden `toString()` method appear like *RequestFacade@422b8dc8* - via the default implementation from `java.lang.Object`.

The hex value is not a hashcode, so as far as I can see it must be a heap memory address offset. This allows you to identify references that refer to the same object (same hex value is same object).

Comment: Thanks Steve! So there are two syntaxes at play here -- one defined by IDEA and the other by the object itself. I didn't realize that. As for the hex value, what does this mean? It looks like it's some kind of unique identifier for the object, but how is it obtained?

Comment: No worries James. I've looked at it and I'm pretty sure the hex value is a heap memory address which is (of course) unique per instance of each object.